# AlarmManager responding at wrong time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

Sorry if answered before, but i looked everywhere but didn't get the proper solution

I am using  AlarmManager to automatically fire a notification at 9am everyday, but when i try to run it on emulator it executes immediately, and every half hour (31-32min to be precise) after that instead of only once at 9am everyday.

Any ideas why? help appreciated.

code is as below:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bsheet);

    notificationAlert(savedInstanceState);

}

    private void notificationAlert(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlarmManager manager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this, Notify.class);
    manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(Home.this,
            0, intent, 0);
    GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
    gcal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    gcal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    gcal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    gcal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    long initTime = gcal.getTimeInMillis();

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, initTime,
            24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
}

}
```

cheers,

**EDIT:** my intention is that, once the app is installed, it fires this alarm at 9am. i have put the alarm in the onCreate, so im not sure if the alarm is only being created everytime i start the app and something weird is happening when i hide the app... again insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9;
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if (alarmTime.compareTo(currentTime) <= 0) {
// check for time
alarmTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thank you. unfortunately, it loads everytime i start the app ... i will try make a few amendments and show a complete solution soon hopefully

Comment: then compare the time and start the alarm

Answer (score 0):

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, initTime, 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Alarm manager will fire immidiatly if `initTime < System.currentTimeMillis()`

[from docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

According to the code you've provided, `gcal.getTimeInMillis()` will return millisecods corresponding to **Today 9.00**. So if you'll try to run your code after this time, **initTime** will be less then current system time which triggers immidiate run of AlarmManager.

To fix this, for example, you can add one day to your calendar before passing its `gcal.getTimeInMillis()` if it is already in past so it will point to **Tomorrow 9.00** to let it run tomorrows morning

**Update1**

Tried code like this and it worked as expected for me - fired service every 10 seconds:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initManager();
}
private void initManager() {
    AlarmManager manager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
    manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, initTime,
            10*1000, pendingIntent);        
}
```

However you can use another option: there is `AlarmManager.set()` method
You can fire it like this

```
long runTime = /* your calendar time + 24 hours in millis*/
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, runTime, pendingIntent);
```

so it will fire your service at `runTime`. And then in the service invoke the same method with recalculated `runTime` for another day so it could look something like that:

```
public MainActivity extends Activity{

    protected onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        ....
        initManager();
    }

    private initManager(){
        ...
        long runTime = /* time of your first alarm/notification/whatever you develope */

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
        pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, runTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And the service:

```
public NotifyService extends Service{
    ...
    public int onStartCommand(...){
         ...
        /* do stuff */

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifyService.class);
        pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        long runTime = /* recalculate it according to the next time of firing this service*/
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, runTime, pendingIntent);

    }
```

}

So your service will register an intent in AlarmManager itself everytime the service fires.

Comment: thanks heaps mate, that explains that bit definitely
however, not sure why it is firing every half an hour. have i positioned by AlarmManager in the wrong place, as part of the onCreate?

Comment: Interesting. Still have no idea what can be wrong in your case. OnCreate shouldn't be an issue. However it works fine in my test case for firing every 10 seconds. If you still stuck on it I can suggest another trick to achieve what you want. Please check the update1 above